# Calling executable .jar on server via javascript

Tags: java, javascript, server-side

Is there any way to pass something to an executable .jar on the server.

Comment: don't really see what's the particular relevance of 'javascript' in this.

Comment: What I meant was if I had a javascript function that returned some text.How could I pass that text to the .jar.

Comment: Its very much possible !.. Using Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a have server side page which calls a jar. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I meant if I had a javascript function that returned some text how could I pass that text to the .jar.I was thinking maybe via ajax and the call exec() with a php script?

Comment: Yon can pass text to a jar as a command line argument or a longer piece of text as a file name (you have to put the content into the file first)

Comment: Can you do this with exec() with php?Send the text to the jar.I am not sure how to call the jar with the text.

Comment: In java you would exec("java","-jar","myjar.jar", my_text); I don't imagine it much different in php which is basically what you would do on the command line. I suggest you try it on the command line first.  It this doesn't work it is because the jar is expecting to get data another way, you need to know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse you can if you desing the app to accept values

```
var editor = document.getElementById(applet_id);
editor.callMethod('com.myclass.applet.Interface', method+'', param+'')+"";
```

we pass the values from javascript to the applet like the example above

Comment: This is an executable .jar not applet.Should have been more clear.I need to pass some text in via String[] args